# Flask-SQLAlchemy mixin with CheckConstraint in __table_args__ results with errors

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to create base Model with single CheckConstraint in base class. When I mixin the base class into flask-sqlalchemy model and try to use it, I get "Can't add unnamed column to column collection".

I tried to play with different ways of declaring this CheckConstraint 
but all resulted with this same error. Any ideas what's causing this?

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declared_attr
from myproject.db import db


class FilteringMixin(db.Model):
    __abstract__ = True

    FILTER_TYPES = {
        'whitelist': 0,
        'blacklist': 1,
    }

    @declared_attr.cascading
    def filter_type(cls):
        return db.Column(db.SmallInteger, nullable=False,
                         default=cls.FILTER_TYPES['whitelist'])

    @declared_attr.cascading
    def __table_args__(cls):
        return (
                 db.CheckConstraint(cls.filter_type.in_(cls.FILTER_TYPES.values())),
        )


class FilteredConnectionType(FilteringMixin, db.Model):
    CONNECTION_TYPES = {
        'wifi': 0,
        'cellular': 1,
    }

    __tablename__ = 'filtered_connection_types'

    id = db.Column(db.BigInteger, primary_key=True)

    connection_type = db.Column(db.SmallInteger, nullable=False,
                                default=CONNECTION_TYPES['cellular'])

    @declared_attr.cascading
    def __table_args__(cls):
        return (
            db.CheckConstraint(cls.connection_type.in_(cls.CONNECTION_TYPES.values())),
        ) + FilteringMixin.__table_args__
```

After that, trying to use it I get:

```
python manage.py shell  
~/myuser/myproject/.venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/declarative/api.py:173: SAWarning: Unmanaged access of declarative attribute __table_args__ from non-mapped class FilteringMixin
  (desc.fget.__name__, cls.__name__))
~/myuser/myproject/.venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/declarative/api.py:173: SAWarning: Unmanaged access of declarative attribute filter_type from non-mapped class FilteringMixin
  (desc.fget.__name__, cls.__name__))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 4, in <module>
    from myproject import create_app, environments, scripts
  File "~/myuser/myproject/myproject/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    import models
  File "~/myuser/myproject/myproject/models/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .filtering_implemented import FilteredConnectionType
  File "~/myuser/myproject/myproject/models/filtering_implemented.py", line 6, in <module>
    class FilteredConnectionType(FilteringMixin, db.Model):
  File "~/myuser/myproject/.venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 609, in __init__
    DeclarativeMeta.__init__(self, name, bases, d)
  File "~/myuser/myproject/.venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/declarative/api.py", line 55, in __init__
    _as_declarative(cls, classname, cls.__dict__)
  File "~/myuser/myproject/.venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/declarative/base.py", line 88, in _as_declarative
    _MapperConfig.setup_mapping(cls, classname, dict_)
  File "~/myuser/myproject/.venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/declarative/base.py", line 103, in setup_mapping
    cfg_cls(cls_, classname, dict_)
  File "~/myuser/myproject/.venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/declarative/base.py", line 131, in __init__
    self._setup_table()
  File "~/myuser/myproject/.venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/declarative/base.py", line 394, in _setup_table
    **table_kw)
  File "~/myuser/myproject/.venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 416, in __new__
    metadata._remove_table(name, schema)
  File "~/myuser/myproject/.venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 60, in __exit__
    compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
  File "~/myuser/myproject/.venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 411, in __new__
    table._init(name, metadata, *args, **kw)
  File "~/myuser/myproject/.venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 488, in _init
    self._init_items(*args)
  File "~/myuser/myproject/.venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 72, in _init_items
    item._set_parent_with_dispatch(self)
  File "~/myuser/myproject/.venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/base.py", line 433, in _set_parent_with_dispatch
    self._set_parent(parent)
  File "~/myuser/myproject/.venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 2553, in _set_parent
    ColumnCollectionMixin._set_parent(self, table)
  File "~/myuser/myproject/.venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 2521, in _set_parent
    self.columns.add(col)
  File "~/myuser/myproject/.venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/base.py", line 509, in add
    "Can't add unnamed column to column collection")
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Can't add unnamed column to column collection
```

Comment: `FilteringMixin` inherits from `do.Model`. `FilteringConnectionType` doesn't need to inherit from both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the real issue is highlighted in two warnings at the top of error output:

```
.../api.py:173: SAWarning: Unmanaged access of declarative attribute __table_args__ from non-mapped class FilteringMixin
  (desc.fget.__name__, cls.__name__))
```

And, as I understand, it is caused by `FilteringMixin.__table_args__` usage and the fix is to use string-based syntax to describe the constraint:

```
class FilteringMixin(object):
    FILTER_TYPES = {
        'whitelist': 0,
        'blacklist': 1,
    }

    @declared_attr
    def filter_type(cls):
        return db.Column(db.SmallInteger, nullable=False,
                         default=cls.FILTER_TYPES['whitelist'])

    @declared_attr
    def __table_args__(cls):
        return (
             db.CheckConstraint(
                 'filter_type in (%s)' %
                 ','.join(str(t) for t in cls.FILTER_TYPES.values())),
        )


class FilteredConnectionType(FilteringMixin, db.Model):
    CONNECTION_TYPES = {
        'wifi': 0,
        'cellular': 1,
    }

    __tablename__ = 'filtered_connection_types'
    # Changed to db.Integer from db.BigInteger because of SQLite
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    connection_type = db.Column(db.SmallInteger, nullable=False,
                                default=CONNECTION_TYPES['cellular'])

    @declared_attr
    def __table_args__(cls):
        return (
            db.CheckConstraint(cls.connection_type.in_(cls.CONNECTION_TYPES.values())),
        ) + FilteringMixin.__table_args__
```

Test code:

```
# saves the record with defaults
conn_type = FilteredConnectionType()
session.add(conn_type)
session.commit()

# raises an error: Check constraint failed
conn_type = FilteredConnectionType(filter_type=3)
session.add(conn_type)
session.commit()
```

Notes:

- FilteringMixin extends object and not the db.Model
- I am not 100% sure, but you probably don't need `@declared_attr.cascading`, but just `@declared_attr`
- In the `FilteringMixin` I renamed used string-based syntax to define the constraint.
- Full example is [here](https://github.com/serebrov/so-questions/blob/master/sql-alchemy/constraint_mixin.py)
- sqlalchemy documentation references - [declared_arrt](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/api.html#sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.declared_attr) and [Mixin and Custom Base Classes](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/mixins.html)

Comment: Thnx. I understand why your code works, but it doesn't do one important task. If I mixin the original `FilteringMixin` into some model that doesn't have its own `__table_args__`, I will still get the correct `CheckContraint` in that model without doing anything. With you replacing it with `@classmethod` this is no longer the case.

Comment: @Tomislav this is a good point, I found another solution using `__table_args__`, the constraint is specified with string-based syntax. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thnx! This is exactly what I was looking for. It would be nice to better understand how does `declarative` actually work. As I understand, it needs classes already initialized to be able to use their attributes. By using string representation, we postpone using the class attributes needed for `CheckContraint` after the `declarative` initialization and this is why your solution works. I've accepted your answer, would like to upvote you but don't have enough rep for that. Anyways, thnx again, this completely answers my original question.

Comment: @Tomislav I can't explain why your original code didn't work, but I have a feeling it is just a rough edge or maybe even a bug. Looking at examples in the documentation, I would expect that the object-like syntax for the `CheckConstraint` should work. Anyway, I am glad that I was able to help.